# Migrating Shibboleth 2 -> 3: WARN Shibboleth.Config : DEPRECATED; WARN Shibboleth.RequestMapper : DEPRECATED

Tags: shibboleth

`/var/log/messages` continuously repeats the following:

```
WARN Shibboleth.Config : DEPRECATED: legacy 2.0 configuration, support will be removed from a future version of the software

WARN Shibboleth.RequestMapper : DEPRECATED: legacy 2.0 configuration, support will be removed from a future version of the software
```

Is this something I should look from `shibboleth2.xml` ?
Maybe this comes from `httpd`?

I know next to nothing about Shibboleth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This comes from using an older shibboleth2.xml configuration file from a Shibboleth SP 2.x install in a Shibboleth SP 3.x install.

Change the first line of shibboleth2.xml from:

```
<SPConfig xmlns="urn:mace:shibboleth:2.0:native:sp:config"
          xmlns:conf="urn:mace:shibboleth:2.0:native:sp:config"
          xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion"
          xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol"
          xmlns:md="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata"
          clockSkew="180">
```

to

```
<SPConfig xmlns="urn:mace:shibboleth:3.0:native:sp:config"
          xmlns:conf="urn:mace:shibboleth:3.0:native:sp:config"
          xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion"
          xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol"
          xmlns:md="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata"
          clockSkew="180">
```

i.e. `urn:mace:shibboleth:2.0:native:sp:config` should become `urn:mace:shibboleth:3.0:native:sp:config`.

I suggest you review the documentation for [Shibboleth Service Provider 3](https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/SP3/ReleaseNotes#ReleaseNotes-DeprecatedSettings) as far as what else has been deprecated. For example, your particular configuration has an issue with your RequestMapper as well... so there may be something in your config there that you need to address.

Comment: Thank you! In addition, as you pointed out and as described here: https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/SP3/UpgradingFromV2 , I needed to change uri -> url for MetadataProvider. (Such useful little changes, surely these new attributes make someone fell the xml is now very tidy ;)

Answer (score 2):

To add to Kellen's answer:

As pointed out here: https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/SP3/UpgradingFromV2

Change
`uri -> url`
or
`file -> path`
for `MetadataProvider`

in addition of changing `xmlns` and `xmlns:conf` from `2.0` to `3.0`.

If you only change the schema version, you will get an erro: `shib_handler: Unable to locate metadata for identity provider`.